# how to mirror + add logo to video?

Tags: ffmpeg, mirror

how to mirror + add logo to video?
How to mirror video, then add logo to video using ffmpeg?

Comment: Share a screenshot of what the output should look like

Comment: Before: [https://imgur.com/a/HhWAK]
After: [https://imgur.com/a/xGEIW]

Then add logo: [https://imgur.com/a/uCfeg]

Comment: Get 404 on all three.

Comment: These links have an extra *]* after them, removing this bracket reveals the image link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To flip a video horizontally, you can use `-vf hflip` (or `vflip` for vertical flipping).

To add a watermark of any image to a video is more complex, especially if you want to position it:

```
-i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2"
```

There are a lot of things you can do with the overlay filter, [check the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1). It gets extremely complex if you also want to scale the overlay, so make sure your logo file is the right size before that.

However, you cannot mix -vf and -filter_complex, so the flipping has to become part of the complex filter.  So, for your desired result, you'd have to do this (assuming you want the logo to be at position 10/10):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "hflip[flipped];[flipped]overlay=x=10:y=10" out.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you @TheSHEEEP
i did it.