# How to mirror the video and add wotermark in node js

Tags: node.js, video, mirror

I wanted to find it here,but I found a similarity to this,but it wasn't for the node.js
[how to mirror + add logo to video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897498/how-to-mirror-add-logo-to-video)

Here we can see a code:ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "hflip[flipped];[flipped]overlay=x=10:y=10" out.mp4
But i didn't understand how i can use it in Node.js
Please,help

Comment: please read this, [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to spawn FFMPEG from your node app:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;


var ffmpeg_process, feedStream=false;
var ops = [-i, input.mp4, -i, logo.png, -filter_complex, "hflip[flipped];[flipped]overlay=x=10:y=10", out.mp4]; 
ffmpeg_process=spawn('ffmpeg', ops);


//in this bit I was writing FFMPEG data to a socket, so I commented out those bits
        ffmpeg_process.stderr.on('data',function(d){
            //socket.emit('ffmpeg_stderr',''+d);
        });
        ffmpeg_process.on('error',function(e){
            console.log('child process error'+e);
            //socket.emit('fatal','ffmpeg error!'+e);
            feedStream=false;
            //socket.disconnect();
        });
        ffmpeg_process.on('exit',function(e){
            console.log('child process exit'+e);
            //socket.emit('fatal','ffmpeg exit!'+e);
            //socket.disconnect();
        });
```

a working example can be seen at [livestream.a.video](https://livestream.a.video). GH: https://github.com/dougsillars/browserLiveStream

Comment: Thanks a lot, Will check it!